# Can't subscribe to DelegateCommand.CanExecuteChanged

Tags: .net, wpf, prism, weak-references, delegatecommand

I have two ViewModels and one contains another. The inner one has a `Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Commands.DelegateCommand` called `PrintCommand`. It is desirable to subscribe to the `CanExecuteChanged` event of this command. This part is implemented as usual:

```
OneViewModel.PrintCommand.CanExecuteChanged += CanExecuteChangedHandler;
```

The problem is that this subscription doesn't work.
Decompiled `CanExecuteChanged` looks like this:

```
public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged  
{  
  add  
  {  
    WeakEventHandlerManager.AddWeakReferenceHandler(ref this._canExecuteChangedHandlers, value, 2);  
  }  
  remove  
  {  
    WeakEventHandlerManager.RemoveWeakReferenceHandler(this._canExecuteChangedHandlers, value);  
  }  
}
```

When I debug, after a couple of steps after subscription the `_canExecuteChangedHandlers` doesn't seem to contain any alive handlers, even though subscriber object still exists.
I'm kind of curious, why is it happening?

Comment: What about your `CanExecuteChangedHandler`? How does it look like? Is this a method or a lambda expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was found in the description of `CanExecuteChanged`. Here it is:

```
/// When subscribing to the <see cref="E:System.Windows.Input.ICommand.CanExecuteChanged"/> event using
///             code (not when binding using XAML) will need to keep a hard reference to the event handler. This is to prevent
///             garbage collection of the event handler because the command implements the Weak Event pattern so it does not have
///             a hard reference to this handler. An example implementation can be seen in the CompositeCommand and CommandBehaviorBase
///             classes. In most scenarios, there is no reason to sign up to the CanExecuteChanged event directly, but if you do, you
///             are responsible for maintaining the reference.
```

This means that we should have a hard reference:

```
private readonly EventHandler commandCanExecuteChangedHandler;
```

And use it like this:

```
this.commandCanExecuteChangedHandler = new EventHandler(this.CommandCanExecuteChanged);
this.command.CanExecuteChanged += this.commandCanExecuteChangedHandler;
```